# Compare Attributes During Partial Iteration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, iteration, partials

I’m working on a Rail app. The app has a partial that is passing in a collection like this:

```
<%= render ‘partial’, collection: @records, as: :record %>
```

The records call two other tables: companies and articles that help populate the partial. Company has_many :articles. My partial has a heading in one table row, which is the company name and another row with the article title. The issue right now is if a company has more than one article, I get multiple rows of company name and article title, like this:

```
Company 1
Article 1

Company 1
Article 2

Company 1
Article 3

Company 2
Article 1

Company 2
Article 2
```

Can I somehow check the company name every time through the iteration and if it is the same, not create the company row? I’m hoping for something like this:

```
Company 1
Article 1
Article 2
Article 3

Company 2
Article 1
Article 2
```

Here is what my partial looks like:

```
<tr>
  <td></td>
  <td colspan="6"class="supplier-name"><%= get_supplier_name(alert) %></td>
</tr>
<tr class="alerts-item">
  <td class="alerts-checkbox">
    <label class="cont">
      <input type="checkbox">
      <span class="checkmark"></span>
    </label>
  </td>
  <td colspan="3" class="alerts-table-info">
    <span>
      <strong><%= link_to get_article_title(alert), get_article_link(alert), target: '_blank' %></strong><br>
      <%= alert.alert.article.snippet %>
    </span>
  </td>
  <td>
    <a href="#link" class="alert-btn-color"><%= get_article_search_group_name(alert) %></a>
  </td>
  <td class="share-col">
    <button class="share-btn">Share</button>
  </td>
  <td>
    <div class="dropdown">
      <div class="dropdown-toggle">Resolve</div>
      <div class="dropdown-content">
        <span class="dropdown-title">Dropdown header</span>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Expandable</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Expand</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </td>
</tr>
```

The `<tr>` with the `<td>get_supplier_name(alert)</td>` is the row that I don't want duplicated.

Comment: Querying `@records` with a `group` clause would be the most optimal and would still allow you to use the performance enhancements of collection rendering.

Answer (score 1):

Use partial for `companies` then each partial `company.html.erb` has partial for `article.html.erb`.